# Attach p:tooltip to an element without an Id

Tags: jquery, primefaces, xhtml, tooltip, legend

I was wondering if there's a way to attach a PrimeFaces Tooltip to a `<td>` element that only has a `class` and some text in it. I am trying to attach some tooltips to legend labels.

I tried using `jQuery` selector to select the specific element but this isn't seem to work. When trying the script below from http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/, everything gets selected, except the labels.

```
<script>
  var elementCount = $( "*" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" ).length;
  $( "body" ).prepend( "<h3>" + elementCount + " elements found</h3>" );
</script>
```

Comment: Attach your code to question

Comment: Check the documentation and check the PF selectors and check PrimeFaces extensions tooltip

Comment: I tried using a selector to do this but it didn't seem to work. After that, I used a example script in the jQuery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/
This selects all elements but it doesn't select the legend.